# VS Code doesn't show autocomplete suggestions for PHPUnit\Framework classes in vendor directory

Tags: php, phpunit, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn PHPUnit framework. I have created a small project on VS code and tried to write my first test case. But VS code doesn't provide any autocomplete suggestions for Classes inside the vendor directory.

I have already installed php7, composer on my system. Also, I have installed vscode-php-intellisense plugin to VS Code. As per the steps suggest [here](https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/vscode-php-development/) I have already tried adding the following settings to `setting.json`. But nothing worked.

```
"intelephense.files.exclude": [
  "**/.git/**",
  "**/.svn/**",
  "**/.hg/**",
  "**/CVS/**",
  "**/.DS_Store/**",
  "**/node_modules/**",
  "**/bower_components/**",
  "**/vendor/**/{Test,test,Tests,tests}/**/*Test.php"
],
```

[image]

I want VS Code to suggest me `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` when I try to type the same. Does anyone know how to get enable this functionality?

Comment: Which version of PHPUnit are you using? I found 7.5 doesn't work, but updating to 8.5 will work as intended.

Comment: What does your composer.json look like?

Comment: I know this is really old, but did you manage to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

A longshot solution and only applicable if you just started the project and did not run any unit tests yet: make sure phpunit is within your project directory: `find . -iname *phpunit*`.  VSCode can't autocomplete if it hasn't indexed the phpunit files.

(This happened to me today because I was in a hurry and had forgotten to run `composer update` / `composer install` yet.)